# How set the android:gravity to TextView from Java side in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, gravity

I can use `android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"` in xml on a textview to get my desired results, but I need to do this programmatically. My textview is inside a `tablerow` if that matters in a `relativelayout`.

I have tried:

```
LayoutParams layoutParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
labelTV.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

But if I understand correctly, that would apply it to the `tablerow`, not the textview?

Answer (score 596, accepted):

```
labelTV.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.BOTTOM);
```

Kotlin version (thanks to Thommy)

```
labelTV.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL or Gravity.BOTTOM
```

Also, are you talking about *gravity* or about layout_gravity? The latter won't work in a *RelativeLayout*.

Comment: Thanks that worked. I feel a little silly now for missing that. Originally the problem was setting the margins on a text field. I guess I assumed because i couldnt find a setMargin() method that setGravity wouldnt exist either.

Comment: Thanks +1, I found the documentation, but as usual it only goes half way, not clearly stating where I get the gravity constants from (Gravity.CENTER etc).

Comment: For anyone who comes here from Google, like me, the Kotlin way is: ```it.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL or Gravity.BOTTOM```

Comment: To me the kotlin way is confusing, why is it `or` and not `and` ?!??!

Comment: @ZooMagic It's not a `Logical` operator (`||`) but a `Bitwise` operator (`|`). The bitwise OR takes the bits of the two values and checks if one (or both) of the bits on the same location is 1, and if so will output this as a 1. For example:  `0010 | 1000 = 1010`, `1010 | 0101 = 1111`, `1100 | 1101 = 1101`

Answer (score 40):

This will center the text in a text view:

```
TextView ta = (TextView) findViewById(R.layout.text_view);
LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams();
lp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
ta.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Comment: That didn't work. "lp.gravity cannot be resolved or is not a field"

Comment: Thats strange because this code works and compiles just fine for me.    How would you set the weight of a textview as their is no setWeight() method?

Comment: I found the problem. Nate is importing android.view.ViewGroup. That class has different kinds of methods and doesn't compile. You should import android.view.WindowManager instead.

Comment: Should better import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams when text view is inside linear layout. Othervise you get ClassCastException

Comment: Thanks, it works. But it is not a complete solution because a type of `LayoutParams` is not defined here and can vary, so it won't compile. You should know a parent layout (for instance, `LinearLayout`) and write it here.

Answer (score 10):

We can set layout gravity on any view like below way-

```
myView = findViewById(R.id.myView);
myView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL|Gravity.RIGHT);
 or
myView.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
```

This is equilent to below xml code

```
<...
 android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
 ...
 .../>
```

Comment: Layout gravity is not same as gravity

Answer (score 3):

You should use `textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);`.

Remember that using

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams =new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
layoutParams2.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
```

won't work. This will set the gravity for the widget and not for it's text.

Answer (score 2):

Use this code

```
        TextView textView = new TextView(YourActivity.this);
        textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.TOP);
        textView.setText("some text");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.BOTTOM);
```

This will set gravity of your textview.

Answer (score 1):

Solved this by doing a few things, first getting the `height` of my `TextView` and diving it by the text `size` to get the total amount of lines possible with the `TextView`.

```Java
int maxLines = (int) TextView.getHeight() / (int) TextView.getTextSize();
```

After you get this value you need to set your `TextView` `maxLines` to this new value.

```Java
TextView.setMaxLines(maxLines);
```

Set the `Gravity` to `Bottom` once the maximum amount of lines has been exceeded and it will scroll down automatically.

```java
if (TextView.getLineCount() >= maxLines) {
    TextView.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
}
```

In order for this to work correctly, you must use `append()` to the `TextView`, If you `setText()` this will not work.

```java
TextView.append("Your Text");
```

The benefit of this method is that this can be used dynamically regardless of the `height` of your `TextView` and the text `size`. If you decide to make modifications to your layout this code would still work.