# How do I set LAYOUTGRAVITY for a TextView in Android? 

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

How do I set a TextView's layout_gravity by code?

I tried with layoutparams without any good result.

```
new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
```

After using this my text just stays where it is standardly, at the top left corner.
Neither the width: FILL_PARENT or the gravity codes do anything.

Comment: Change TableRow to FrameLayout.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL)
```

Answer (score 2):

u can use gravity in code by using below code :

```
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.MyButtonId);
    // need to cast to LinearLayout.LayoutParams to access the gravity field
    LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams)button.getLayoutParams(); 
    params.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
    button.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Answer (score 1):

[Android set the gravity for a TextView programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3775705/android-set-the-gravity-for-a-textview-programmatically)
Have you seen this response ?

```
TextView tv  = (TextView) findViewById(R.layout.text_view);   
tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.BOTTOM);
```

Comment: yes and i tried everything and non works. I edit my question.

Answer (score 0):

```
 layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.vendor_detail_lay);
    LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
    linearLayout.setOrientation(0);
    txtveiw = new TextView(NewVendorDetailActivity.this);
    txtveiw.setLayoutParams(Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    txtveiw.setId(itemId);
    txtveiw.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DataBaseHelper.KEYNAME)));

    linearLayout.addView(txtveiw);
    layout.addView(linearLayout);
```

Comment: i am give jaset example u can remove ande only set Gravity

Answer (score -1):

best solution for keeping existing layout params:

- You need to use LayoutParams of the parent layout (hence **layout_**gravity)
- for example if parent is FrameLayout do:

  ```
  FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = 
      new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(textView.getLayoutParams());
  layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.RIGHT;
  textView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
  ```