# How to change TextView gravity programmatically using constraint layout

Tags: android

In xml layout, gravity of the TextView is setted. In some condition, I want to change the gravity of the TextView in my coding.I have tried to set like this:

```
title.setGravity(Gravity.START);
```

but no change.

In xml I have aligned text view gravity to center.
I have to change this gravity to START in some condition programmatically:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text=" "
        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

So how to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android set the gravity for a TextView programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3775705/android-set-the-gravity-for-a-textview-programmatically)

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3775705/android-set-the-gravity-for-a-textview-programmatically

Comment: Your `TextView` has `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`  which as you guess will wrap it's content. That's why if you change the gravity you won't notice any difference. You will have to change `layour_height` to `0dp` because you are using `ConstraintLayout` and it will work.

Comment: @hardartcore I have tried adding like this in my code```textView.setHeight(0); but now my text is not even displayed

Comment: You should add it in xml file & make your `layour_width` to `0dip` too, so it can use only the constraints. Keep in mind that you have to set all constraints, left / right / top / bottom

Answer (score 1):

```
 TextView tview= (TextView) findViewById(R.layout.text_view);
 LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams();
 lp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
 tview.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Comment: what do I want to pass inside ``` new LayoutParams()```

Comment: you have to set layout forms for your textview  tview.setLayoutParams(lp);

Comment: @Neo I have tried it but nothing changed...I have already aligned text gravity in center in xml itself.  In some cases I want to change that gravity...But after changing also getting same aligment as in xml

Comment: share your xml file

Answer (score 1):

Finally found a solution for my question.
I have tried doing this in my code

```
ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams params = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
params.horizontalBias = 0.2f; 
myView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

It worked for me...

Comment: You can add horizontal bias using your xml and just update the gravity too.

Answer (score 0):

This is perfect for setting the gravity of constraint layout, Here "container" is parent layout and "popup" also constraint layout but its child layout of "container"..

```
val container = findviewbyid.....
val DialogPopup = findviewbyid...

     val constraintSet = ConstraintSet()
        constraintSet.clone(container)
//whole code is setting your content or layout at bottom left corner

//below code is setting gravity at start.
  constraintSet.connect(DialogPopup .getId(),ConstraintSet.START,
                container.getId(),
                ConstraintSet.START)


// below code is for setting gravity at bottom
 constraintSet.connect(
            DialogPopup.getId(),
            ConstraintSet.BOTTOM,
            container.getId(),
            ConstraintSet.BOTTOM
        )
        constraintSet.applyTo(mBinding.container)
```